# Trouble resolving user names from a separate state in Angular project with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx, selector, reduce

I'm working on an Angular project using ngrx, where I have two states—one for users and another for projects. In the project state, each project has an Author and an Editor. The user state contains users as a Key-Value object, with only the keys fetched from the backend. I already have user data loaded in another state.

I am trying to use the user state to resolve the names of users in the project reducer, but my current implementation is not working. Here's the code:

In the User Selector:

```
export const getUserNameByIdSelector = (ids: number) => createSelector(
selectPeople, (state: PeopleState) => state.users.find(user => ids === user.Id).Name);
```

In the Project Reducer:

```
case ActionTypes.LoadAllProjectsSuccess: {
let projects = action.payload;
projects.map(p => ({
    ...p,
    Author: { ...p.Author, Value: getUserNameByIdSelector(p.Author.Key as number) },
    Editor: { ...p.Editor, Value: getUserNameByIdSelector(p.Editor.Key as number) }
}));
return {
    ...state,
    projects: projects
};}
```

I'm facing issues with this code, and the names are not being resolved correctly. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You main issue is that you are calling `getUserNameByIdSelector` directly without passing it as an argument into the store select function. You won't get the value you expect because the return type of `getUserNameByIdSelector` is `MemoizedSelector`, not the value.

That being said, there really is no good way that I know of to call a selector within a reducer. I would call that an anti-pattern.

What you might be able to do is to call your action with the data you need from within an effect, but that seems a bit hacky to me as well.

Or, you might want to think about refactoring your states so that you have all the data that relates to one another in a single slice of state.